# Ubuntu server default password using Raspberry Pi image?

Tags: server, password, raspberrypi

I've just installed Ubuntu Server on my Raspberry Pi 2 B and the download page says that the default username and password are both "ubuntu", but the system says that the password is incorrect. What's wrong?

Comment: Have you tried pressing ENTER without entering a password?

Comment: I don't think that enter works - it isn't possible to use the su command without any password so..

Comment: I found that it takes a few minutes after it boots for Ubuntu on the Pi to create the 'ubuntu' user and its password. is the correct answer but in my case this didn't happen

Answer (score 56):

I found that it takes a few minutes after it boots for Ubuntu on the Pi to create the 'ubuntu' user and its password.

I searched for a solution and found this question.  The existing answer was no help.  When I went back, some text had come up on the console about cloud init and SSH keygen.  I tried again, and ubuntu:ubuntu worked!

Comment: I had this very issue with my raspberry-pi. After several unsuccessful tries login in, and without having done any change at all, just out of the blue I was able to login.

Comment: Agreed. If you wait for a while after the login prompt with a monitor attached, you'll see it start to print SHA fingerprints, etc. After these are printed, the login works.

Comment: the main issue with no login is if you set static IP on the network config - DO NOT set static IP and access to the server console works as expected

Answer (score 14):

Try these:

1)
You can SSH into the Pi 4 with:
User: ubuntu
Pass: ubuntu

*** It will then ask for new password. ***
This only works if you have ethernet cable connected.

Source: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=254649

2) and try ..has the default username pi and default password raspberry

3) The default password is root which you can easily change once you are booted into the Pi by running 'passwd' command.  Source: https://www.linux.com/tutorials/getting-started-raspberry-pi-2-install-linux-and-access-ssh/

Comment: The question states that he cannot log in with ubuntu:ubuntu on first boot. Your answer for him to log in with ubuntu:ubuntu does not work for him.