# How to execute the first raspberry pi 3 login

Tags: server, login, password, raspberrypi, arm

**Context**

- I downloaded the latest Raspberry Pi image (64x server) from https://ubuntu.com/download/raspberry-pi
- I created the image as per instructions for mac on https://ubuntu.com/download/iot/installation-media
- My specs are Raspberry pi 3 model b

The Boot goes fine, the connected ethernet connects and system-wize everything is up and running.
The login fails however. I'm trying to login using

- user: ubuntu
- pass: ubuntu

as per instructions on https://ubuntu.com/download/raspberry-pi
I'm however greeted by the username or password incorrect message. Upon checking the user-data file on the sd-card reveals the following configuration:

```
# On first boot, set the (default) ubuntu user's password to "ubuntu" and
# expire user passwords
chpasswd:
  expire: true
  list:
  - ubuntu:ubuntu
```

So by all means logging in should have worked, what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out by accident. apparently the default login doesn't work on TTY0 (the default that the raspberry pi boots with), switching to TTY1 or above and retrying to login solves all problems.

Comment: What I found (documented in https://askubuntu.com/a/1236415/10542) was that it's a timing issue. Waiting until some `cloud-init` text comes up on TTY0, then trying ubuntu:ubuntu worked reliably for me.

Answer (score 0):

the curse does not move when entering password. type it anyway and pay attention to what you type. I did this with pi3b hooked to a older tv, and the first three spaces   was blocked out by the tv frame. it took several tries before i noticed it was asking for a new password. type it in,  curse will not move, press enter